# Retain bidirectionality with Ranges-v3 view::join

Tags: c++, c++14, range-v3

I've run into some difficulty with the `view::join` function object of the (amazing) Ranges-v3 library. My client code is dependent upon the presence of a back method (and would greatly appreciate random access iterators) for an aggregate view of a collection of ranges.

After reviewing the [relevant documentation](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1v3_1_1join__view.html) it seems that a `back` method is compatible with instantations of the join_view class template, but I've been unable to instantiate it as such.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

struct Foo{
    std::vector<int> i = {1,2,3,4};
    const std::vector<int>& data() const { return this->i; }
};

int main(){
    std::vector< Foo > foos = { Foo(), Foo(), Foo() };

    auto data = []( auto&& foo ){ return foo.data() | ranges::view::all; };
    auto flat = foos | ranges::view::transform(data) | ranges::view::join;
    std::cout << flat.back() << std::endl; // compiler error
}
```

The relevant bits of the compiler error message are:

```
main.cpp:17:28: error: no matching function for call to 'ranges::v3::join_view<ranges::v3::transform_view<ranges::v3::range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Foo*, std::vector<Foo> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Foo*, std::vector<Foo> > >, main()::<lambda(auto:1&&)> >, void>::back()'

 std::cout << flat.back() << std::endl; // compiler error

/usr/local/include/range/v3/range_interface.hpp:116:34: note: candidate: template<class D, int _concept_requires_115, typename std::enable_if<((_concept_requires_115 == 43) || ((std::is_same<D, ranges::v3::join_view<ranges::v3::transform_view<ranges::v3::range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Foo*, std::vector<Foo> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Foo*, std::vector<Foo> > >, main()::<lambda(auto:1&&)> >, void> >() && ranges::v3::concepts::models<ranges::v3::concepts::BoundedView, T>()) && ranges::v3::concepts::models<ranges::v3::concepts::BidirectionalView, T>())), int>::type <anonymous> > ranges::v3::range_reference_t<D> ranges::v3::range_interface<Derived, Inf>::back() [with D = D; int _concept_requires_115 = _concept_requires_115; typename std::enable_if<((_concept_requires_115 == 43) || ((std::is_same<D, Derived>() && ranges::v3::concepts::models<ranges::v3::concepts::BoundedView, D>()) && ranges::v3::concepts::models<ranges::v3::concepts::BidirectionalView, D>())), int>::type <anonymous> = <enumerator>; Derived = ranges::v3::join_view<ranges::v3::transform_view<ranges::v3::range<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Foo*, std::vector<Foo> >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Foo*, std::vector<Foo> > >, main()::<lambda(auto:1&&)> >, void>; bool Inf = false]

         range_reference_t<D> back()

/usr/local/include/range/v3/range_interface.hpp:115:17: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, int>'

                 CONCEPT_REQUIRES_(Same<D, Derived>() && BoundedView<D>() && BidirectionalView<D>())>
```

The first requirement seems to be enforcing proper use of the CRTP, which is satisfied. So the `join_view` violates either the `BoundedView` or `BidirectionalView` concepts (or both). I was able to quickly eliminate the former as a possiblity.

```
auto flat = foos 
  | ranges::view::transform(data) 
  | ranges::view::join 
  | ranges::view::bounded;
std::cout << flat.back() << std::endl; // compiler error
```

In this case, `flat` satisfies the `BoundedView` concept, but the error message remains unchanged.

To verify the `BidirectionalView`, I attempted examined the iterators of the `join_view`, but encountered (what is suspect) is a bug.

```
auto it = flat.begin();
std::cout << *it << std::endl; // correct
++it; std::cout << *it << std::endl; // correct
--it; std::cout << *it << std::endl; // doesn't actually decrement
auto other = --it;
std::cout << *it << ' ' << *other << std::endl; // also doesn't decrement
```

I've written up a [live version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6607189d4c5b362) for easy inspection.

Has anyone had any luck instantiating a bidirectional `join_view`? Any suggestion of how I might achieve similar behavior without copying the underlying data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Range-v3's `join` view satisfies `InputRange`, but not `Forward` or anything stronger. It has to do with how the join is accomplished. While iterating over an inner range, the range needs to be stored somewhere. That somewhere is in a member of the `join_view` object. In other words, `join_view` is mutated while you iterate over it. For that reason, it cannot model any range category stronger than `Input`.